# Is there a possibility to override the standard look of the knowledge articles attached as PDFs in the send email functionality

Tags: email, case, pdf, knowledge, articles

Knowledge Articles are sent through the send email functionality as PDF attachments. Currently the knowledge articles that are sent as PDF’s attached to the email have the standard salesforce look and feel. Each article type should display a different template based on the article type. We need to change that. Is it possible to achieve this without having to recreate the standard functionality in visual force just for this purpose? If not how should it be done through a visualforce page.